# JsonProvider unusable

Tags: json, f#, type-providers

Trying to use the json type provider, unsuccesfully. After runnings the following commands :

- Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
- Install-Package FSharp.Data -Version 2.2.5

I can't seem to be able to make the following error go away : JsonProvider is undefined

```
open FSharp.Data
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders

type JsonObj =  JsonProvider<"http://shopicruit.myshopify.com/products.json">
```

I'd like to know what's currently missing because I can't see why this F# snippet is not right.

**UPDATE**

Here's a capture of my installs

[image]

[image]

Here's a capture of my type provider settings. (They were already enabled). I don't get what I'm missing at the moment...

[image]

Comment: Are you working in a script file (`.fsx`) or in an `.fs` file inside a project?

Comment: Fs file inside my my project

Comment: And did NuGet correctly install the package and add it to project references?

Comment: Also, check that you didn't disable the type provider when it was loaded for the first time. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212194.aspx

Comment: Is the `FSharp.Data` package installed in the right project? It's something that gets me from time to time, including when I was trying to reproduce your issue - I had installed the NuGet package into a different project in my solution. =P

Comment: I could always start a new project inside a new test solution to verify but I think I made the correct installations. I'll double check just to be sure. I'll get back to you @roujo

Comment: You can check by right-clicking "References" under your project and picking "Manage NuGet Packages". Alternatively, if you've just installed the packages, you can look at the Package Manager Console and see what the value in the "Default Project" dropdown is - it was set to the wrong project in my case.

Comment: Just to make sure, can you try in a new project with *just* `Install-Package FSharp.Data`? You don't need any other library for JSON provider. Also, delete the second line in your code snippet. You only need `open FSharp.Data`.

Comment: I've just did that and it work! I don't know how to fix it in my previous project... But good catch @tomasPetricek

Comment: See my previous comment re: how to check if the package is installed in the right project. If it isn't, you can use `Uninstall-Package` to remove the packages from the projects they shouldn't be in, then install them to the correct one. =)

Comment: I guess that should do it @roujo Put it as an answer. I'll check and put as the right answer for my issues.. I'll keep in mind to double check in new project if that kind of thing happens again

Comment: Quick question, related to this thread. If my provider picks on a IEnumerable such A list. How could I parametrized such a type when the signature is JsonProvider<...> A list. When I try to use it, it shows me that's  the incorrect way to do so @tomasPetricek

Comment: if you do `type Foo = JsonProvider<"....">` then you can refer to provided types via `Foo.Root` and `Foo.Whatever`. If that's what you mean? Otherwise, feel free to open a new more detailed question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When installing a NuGet Package to a project via the Package Manager Console, make sure that the value in the "Default project" field is the project you want to install the package to:
[image: Package Manager Console]

This has happened to me many times, including while trying to reproduce your issue. Also, as @Tomas Petricek says in the comments - both to your question and to my previous attempt at an answer here - you don't need to open `Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders`. `JsonProvider` works with just a reference to `FSharp.Data`.

In case you mistakenly installed the package to the wrong project, you can either:

- Use `Uninstall-Package` to remove it, again making sure the "Default project" field targets the project in question, or;
- Right-click on "References" under said project, then pick "Manage NuGet Packages". This will open the NuGet Package Manager window, from which you can also uninstall whatever you don't need.

[image: NuGet Package Manager]

Comment: For `JsonProvider`, you need just `FSharp.Data` and nothing else. (Not `FSharp.Data.TypeProviders` and also not `Newtonsoft.Json`.) But I suppose the second line in OP's code would be giving an error if he didn't already have reference to `FSharp.Data.TypeProviders`.

Comment: That's odd, it wouldn't compile on my sandbox project without adding the `FSharp.Data.TypeProviders` part. I'll double check and come back.

Comment: Alright, you're right - I spoke too fast. I added `FSharp.Data.TypeProviders` because I was getting an error on the `open`, but after re-testing I noticed that the `JsonProvider` works without the open at all. I'll go ahead and delete this. Sorry!

Comment: @TomasPetricek That should do it. Thanks for the help in troubleshooting this. I just noticed by opening the Package Manager that you're one of the owners of the FSharp.Data project - thank you for that as well! =D